# Want Row Number on Group of column in MY SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have one table in MYSQL
It has data like

```
Id Name 
1  test
1  test
1  test123
2  test222
3  test333
```

I want the data like

```
Id Name     RowNum
1  test       1
1  test       2
1  test123    1
2  test222    1
3  test333    1
```

Means i want assign row number on group of Id  and Name ?

what should the script for same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This table definition will achieve what you want.

```
CREATE TABLE  `test` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `RowNum` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`Name`,`RowNum`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Populate table with data

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1,"test",null),
(1,"test",null),
(1,"test123",null),
(2,"test222",null),
(3,"test333",null);
```

Select data from table

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result

```
1, 'test', 1
1, 'test', 2
1, 'test123', 1
2, 'test222', 1
3, 'test333', 1
```

For doing it in a query here is a rather crude way of doing it.

```
select g.id,g.name,g.rownum 
from (
    select t.id,t.name,
        @running:=if(@previous=concat(t.id,t.name),@running,0) + 1 as rownum,
        @previous:=concat(t.id,t.name) 
    from test t
    order by concat(t.id,t.name) 
) g;
```

Comment: Thanks guy, If is possible without create primary key , and possible with query.

Comment: This method relies on having a composite primary key. There could be others ways of doing it with a query. It was just the solution i knew beforehand.

Comment: @Paresh, I added a query to get the same effect.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way with a query that is simpler (at least for me):

```
SELECT
a.Id, a.Name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test
 WHERE Id = a.Id AND `Name` = a.Name AND row_id < a.row_id) AS RowNum
FROM test AS a
ORDER BY a.row_id;
```

This supposes there exists a global `row_id` (for instance an auto-increment primary key in your table).

Answer (score 2):

Oracle and MSSQL would support

```
SELECT Id, Name, row_number() OVER(partition by Id, Name order by Id) AS RowNum FROM table
```

(answer doesn't help the OP who is on MySQL, but added for completeness)

Comment: I believe MYSQL now supports this syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, name, (select count(*) + 1 from table as i where i.id = p.id and i.id < p.id ) from table p;
```

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE tablename SET RowNum=(SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM tablename WHERE Id=Name)`

Comment: I want the rownum as if id and name are same then it should be increment by one