# MySQL SELECT Counter, Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

im not sure if what I am asking for is possible... but it probably is lol.

Basically, I have two tables, tracks and albums.

I want to display a list of all tracks and get the name from the albums part.

The tables look like this:

```
tbl_tracks
id - int, auto increment, primary key
album_id - int
title - varchar 50
```

and

```
tbl_albums
id - int, auto increment, primary key
title - varchar 50
```

Now, i run the query:

SELECT `tbl_tracks`.`title`, `tbl_albums`.`title` FROM `tbl_tracks`, `tbl_albums` WHERE `tbl_tracks`.`album_id` = `tbl_albums`.`id` GROUP BY `tbl_tracks`.`title`

Now that prints out the following list:

```
Track1 Artist1
Track2 Artist1
Track3 Artist1
Track1 Artist2
```

etc..etc..

(The track names arnt as posted i did that for clarity sake)

Now what i want to do is select another column that numbers each track by artist so the above query would output:

```
1 Track1 Artist1
2 Track2 Artist1
3 Track3 Artist1
1 Track1 Artist2
```

But i want to do that without any other columns added to the database or without any serverside loops, how would i do this?

Comment: please post the table schema of `tbl_tracks`. If you do not have a column providing an ordering, it is unlikely that this is possible without table alteration.

Comment: sorry, forgot to put in code blocks

Comment: It is common practice to have an auto-incremented id column for each table. Why don't you just use the id col in tbl_tracks?

Comment: What does the ID column signify in `tbl_tracks`?

Comment: both ids are autoincremented

i cant use the id for tracks, because track1 artist2 would be 4 not 1

Comment: There is a feature for this in MS SQL Server ROW_NUMBER which you can read about here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx.  I haven't seen anything for MySQL that makes this easy

Comment: Why is there even a GROUP BY in your query?

Comment: I dont actually know :/ i removed it and the results were the same, beats me lol

Comment: @Ozzy, even though those rows are `AUTOINCREMENT`, and one could formulate a query abusing that, I don't think that it is reasonable to rely on that number to determine track order. From a data perspective, it doesn't make sense as someone could have entered the tracks out of order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want Row Number on Group of column in MY SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026956/want-row-number-on-group-of-column-in-my-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT @rn := if(@g = tbl_albums.id, @rn+1, 1) rownumber,
       tbl_tracks.title, tbl_albums.title,
  @g := tbl_albums.id
FROM (select @g:=null, @rn:=0) initvars
CROSS JOIN tbl_tracks
INNER JOIN tbl_albums on tbl_tracks.album_id = tbl_albums.id
ORDER BY tbl_albums.id, tbl_tracks.title;
```

Comment: If the last column annoys you, put it in a subquery and SELECT only the first 3 columns

Comment: `<devil's advocate>`What happens if tracks are entered out of order?`</devil's advocate>`

Comment: @Kevin - In which case, leave it at `ORDER BY tbl_albums.id` which should filesort the `tbl_tracks.title` according to order of entry, or `order by tbl_albums.id, tbl_tracks.id` etc.

Comment: Yes but, form my understanding, OP is hoping that this answer will give him the real track number/order from the album itself. I just wanted to throw that curveball in there to make him think, since it is impossible to know that data point, only assume it.

Answer (score 0):

We need to do something like ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By AlbumTitle).
Based on the trick defined in this [article](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/) for Analytical functinons in MySQl.

```
SELECT MO.*,
       @_rowNumber := @_rowNumber + 1
  FROM
       (
        SELECT m.*
          FROM
               (
                Select @_albumTitle := NULL
               ) V,
               (
                SELECT tbl_tracks.title As TrackTitle, 
                       tbl_albums.title As AlbumTitle
                  FROM tbl_tracks, 
                       tbl_albums 
                 WHERE tbl_tracks.album_id = tbl_albums.id
               ) m
         ORDER BY m.AlbumTitle,m.TrackTitle
       ) MO
 WHERE (CASE WHEN @_albumTitle IS NULL 
               OR @_albumTitle <> MO.AlbumTitle THEN @_rowNumber := 0 END IS NOT NULL)
   AND (@_albumTitle := MO.AlbumTitle) IS NOT NULL
```

NOTE: I have experience only in MS SQL, so this query may be wrong syntactically. And this query is Untested in MySql. I just read the code from article above and tried to follow the same approach.