# generate index columns for "ORDER BY x, y"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I use this query to summarize the contents of the table `export_blocks`, aggregated by user and date, and save it as a new table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE export_days
SELECT user_id DATE(submitted) AS date_str,
FROM export_blocks
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(submitted)
ORDER BY user_id, submitted
```

How can I, for each `user_id` get an incremental index for the date of records for that user? The indicies should start at 1 for each user, following the ORDER BY. I.e. I'd like to generate the `date_index` of the output below using SQL:

```sql
user_id date_str   date_index
brian   2014-06-10 1
brian   2014-06-12 2
brian   2014-06-15 3
louis   2014-06-08 1
louis   2014-06-16 2
lucy    2013-11-15 1
(etc...)
```

I've been trying https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493480/1297830 but I cannot get it to work. It stops the counters prematurely, giving too low numbers for `id_no` and `date_no`.

Comment: Your problem is not clear.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Show your actual query including the `group by`

Comment: I've updated the question. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Joachim's excellent answer I worked out the solution. It also works when there's multiple rows per day for each user.

```
CREATE TABLE export_days
SELECT 
    user_id, DATE(submitted) AS date_str,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(submitted))+1 FROM export_blocks WHERE user_id = a.user_id AND submitted < a.submitted) date_no
FROM export_blocks a
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(submitted)
ORDER BY user_id, submitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Basing it on your sample query, you can do simple (dependent) subqueries to get the result;

```
SELECT id, date_str, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)+1 FROM mytable WHERE id < a.id) id_no,
  (SELECT COUNT(id)+1 FROM mytable WHERE id = a.id AND date_str < a.date_str) date_no
FROM mytable a
ORDER BY id;
```

...or you could do a couple of self joins;

```
SELECT a.id, a.date_str, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.id)+1 id_no,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.date_str)+1 date_no
FROM mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b ON a.id > b.id
LEFT JOIN mytable c ON a.id = c.id AND a.date_str > c.date_str
GROUP BY a.id, a.date_str
ORDER BY a.id, a.date_str;
```

[An SQLfiddle showing both in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29daf/1).

Sadly neither is really a very performant solution, but since MySQL lacks analytical (ie ranking) functions, the options are limited. Using user variables to do the ranking is also an option, however they're notoriously tricky to use and aren't portable so I'd go there only if performance demands it.

Comment: Thank you, Joachim. This definitely looks like the way to go. Performance is not an issue is I only need to do this once. I don't quite understand the ``FROM mytable a`` syntax. Is ``a`` a reference to the current row of ``mytable`` in the "outer namespace" outside the subquery?

Comment: @Jonas In the subquery version, `a` is just an alias for `mytable` in the outer query. That allows the inner query to reference `a.id` so that it knows which row it should currently work with. If we didn't alias it and used `mytable.id` in the inner query, it would be hidden by the inner query's own `mytable`.