# MySQL - Convert a duplicate value in an unique with an increment concatenation

Tags: mysql

Just before, I posted a question about [getting a counter for each duplicate values in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463628/mysql-get-a-counter-for-each-duplicate-value)

Now I'll extend this question such as:

```
+------+------+------+
| id   | data | num  | 
+------+------+------+
| 1    | a    |      | 
| 2    | a    |      |
| 3    | a    |      |
| 4    | b    |      |
| 5    | b    |      |
| 6    | c    |      |
| 7    | d    |      |
| 8    | a    |      |
| 9    | b    |      | 
+------+------+------+
```

could be updated into:

```
+------+------+------+
| id   | data | num  | 
+------+------+------+
| 1    | a    |   a1 | 
| 2    | a    |   a2 |
| 3    | a    |   a3 |
| 4    | b    |   b1 |
| 5    | b    |   b2 |
| 6    | c    |   c1 |
| 7    | d    |   d1 |
| 8    | a    |   a4 |
| 9    | b    |   b3 | 
+------+------+------+
```

A big bow to [bluefeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) anyway!

Comment: This isn't a question. Why did you post this and not edit your first question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET num = ( SELECT num FROM 
(
select id,
  concat(data, cast(group_row_number as char)) as num
from
(
  select id, data,
        @num := if(@data = `data`, @num + 1, 1) as group_row_number,
        @data := `data` as dummy
  from
  (
    select id, data
    from mytable, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
  ) x
  order by data, id
) x  order by id
) tempSort

 WHERE mytable.ID = tempSort.ID );
```

Thks again @bluefeet!!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just want to [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) the values together:

```
select data, group_row_number, 
  concat(data, cast(group_row_number as char)) as num,
  overall_row_num
from
(
  select data,
        @num := if(@data = `data`, @num + 1, 1) as group_row_number,
        @data := `data` as dummy, overall_row_num
  from
  (
    select data, @rn:=@rn+1 overall_row_num
    from yourtable, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
  ) x
  order by data, overall_row_num
) x
order by overall_row_num
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb591/59)

Comment: Yes, but I also want to update my table by relating the ID of this select with the ID of the existing one.

Comment: @kairos does your table have an `ID` field on it like you displayed?

Comment: Yep. just what I've showed above. The table has an ID

Comment: I always forget about concat. Nice....