# how to generate duplicate number if same number in table sql

Tags: sql

i need to generate duplicate number in two digit if same number is insert in table.

i need result looking something like this...thank you.

```
ID    duplicate_id
1423     01
1423     02 
1423     03
1423     04
5246     01
5246     02
5246     03
8967     01
```

can anyone help me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Get a counter for each duplicate value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463628/mysql-get-a-counter-for-each-duplicate-value)

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with (`SQL Server`)

```
SELECT id, RIGHT('0'+ CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By ID Order By ID)) as varchar(2)), 2) as     duplicate_id
FROM tbl
```

Comment: i am getting answer like --01
02
03
04 for same number(like counter)

Comment: isn't that the requirement (based on the different ID's)?

Answer (score 2):

mysql version

```
select id,duplicate_id 
  from (
          select id,                 
                 @row:=if(@prev=id,@row,0) + 1 as duplicate_id,
                 @prev:=id
            from tbl
        order by id
)t
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463628/mysql-get-a-counter-for-each-duplicate-value)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7173e/1)

Sql server version

```
;WITH Data AS
(  
   SELECT
       ID, 
       duplicate_id= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC)
   FROM tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM Data
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01189/5)

Comment: showing error like this -- Must declare the scalar variable "@row".