# Incrementing count ONLY for duplicates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, duplicates, window-functions

Here is my MySQL table. I updated the question by adding an 'id' column to it (as instructed in the comments by others).

```
id    data_id

1     2355
2     2031
3     1232
4     9867
5     2355
6     4562
7     1232
8     2355
```

I want to add a new column called `row_num` to assign an incrementing number ONLY for duplicates, as shown below. Order of the results does not matter.

```
id    data_id     row_num
3     1232        1
7     1232        2
2     2031        null
1     2355        1
5     2355        2
8     2355        3
6     4562        null
4     9867        null
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464202/10181476) answer and came up with the code below. But following code adds a count of '1' to non-duplicate values too, how can I modify below code to add a count only for duplicates?

```
select data_id,row_num
from (
      select data_id,
             @row:=if(@prev=data_id,@row,0) + 1 as row_num,
             @prev:=data_id
        from my_table
)t
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: MySQL version 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that `id` is the column that defines the order on the rows.

In MySQL 8 you can use `row_number()` to get the number of each `data_id` and a `CASE` with `EXISTS` to exclude the rows which have no duplicate.

```
SELECT t1.data_id,
       CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM my_table t2
                             WHERE t2.data_id = t1.data_id
                                   AND t2.id <> t1.id) THEN
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.data_id
                              ORDER BY t1.id)
       END row_num
       FROM my_table t1;
```

In older versions you can use a subquery counting the rows with the same `data_id` but smaller `id`. With an `EXISTS` in a `HAVING` clause you can exclude the rows that have no duplicate.

```
SELECT t1.data_id,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM my_table t2
               WHERE t2.data_id = t1.data_id
                     AND t2.id < t1.id
               HAVING EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM my_table t2
                                     WHERE t2.data_id = t1.data_id
                                           AND t2.id <> t1.id)) + 1 row_num
      FROM my_table t1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=310831c87705a0b5eb46bc7b8229c5b8)

Comment: The first value of the set of duplicates does not get a number. Eg. when there are 3 duplicates, only the last two values get a count as 1 & 2

Comment: The second code sample solved my problem. If you can explain a little more about how this code works, will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this more efficiently with window functions only:

```
select
    data_id,
    case when count(*) over(partition by data_id) > 1
        then row_number() over(partition by data_id order by data_id) row_num
    end
from mytable
```

When the window count returns more than `1`, you know that the current `data_id` has duplicates, in which case you can use `row_number()` to assign the incrementing number.

Note that, in absence of an ordering columns to uniquely identify each record within groups sharing the same `data_id`, it is undefined which record will actually get each number.

Comment: Explanation about the importance of ID column was very useful, I updated the question by adding an ID column.

Answer (score 0):

Join with a query that returns the number of duplicates.

```
select t1.data_id, IF(t2.dups > 1, row_num, '') AS row_num
from (
      select data_id,
             @row:=if(@prev=data_id,@row,0) + 1 as row_num,
             @prev:=data_id
        from my_table
        order by data_id
) AS t1
join (
    select data_id, COUNT(*) AS dups
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY data_id
) AS t2 ON t1.data_id = t2.data_id
```

Comment: It does not increment the count, the count is given as '1' for each duplicate value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the old "order" of the old table, you need much more code

> ```
> SELECT 
>     data_id, IF (row_num = 1 AND cntid = 1, NULL,row_num) 
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         @row:=IF(@prev = t1.data_id, @row, 0) + 1 AS row_num,
>         cntid,
>             @prev:=t1.data_id data_id
>     FROM
>         (SELECT 
>         *
>     FROM
>        my_table
>     ORDER BY data_id) t1 
>     INNER JOIN (SELECT Count(*) cntid,data_id FROM my_table GROUP BY data_id)t2 
>      ON t1.data_id = t2.data_id) t2
> ```
>
> ```
> data_id | IF (row_num = 1 AND cntid = 1, NULL,row_num)
> ------: | -------------------------------------------:
>    1232 |                                            1
>    1232 |                                            2
>    2031 |                                         null
>    2355 |                                            1
>    2355 |                                            2
>    2355 |                                            3
>    4562 |                                         null
>    9867 |                                         null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f558e05067327caf5f791a552dbe4954)*

Comment: Isn't this still adds a count of '1' on the non-duplicate values too? I would need to get rid of the count '1' on non-duplicate rows? Please see the expected results table in the question.

Comment: Ok this delete all one that have a count equal to 1