# MySQL "number" rows in result

Tags: mysql

This is my first question, so please bear with me.
I have a stored procedure which selects orders and order line location ids. In the result, I need the ability to "sequence" each location in each order.

the query so far is:

```
   select DISTINCT oh.order_id, oline.ship_location_id, null
    from op_order_header as oh
    inner join op_order_line as oline ON
        oh.order_id = oline.order_id
    inner join co_products as pr ON
        oline.product_id = pr.product_id and
        pr.inventory_type = 'inventory'
    where oh.order_status = 'COMPLETE'
```

the result is:

```
+----------+------------------+----------+
| order_id | ship_location_id | sequence |
+----------+------------------+----------+
|    24737 |             6621 |     NULL |
|    24738 |             6623 |     NULL |
|    24743 |             6634 |     NULL |
|    24743 |             6635 |     NULL |
+----------+------------------+----------+
```

the required result is:

```
+----------+------------------+----------+
| order_id | ship_location_id | sequence |
+----------+------------------+----------+
|  1224737 |             6621 |         1|
|  1324738 |             6623 |         1|
|  1224743 |             6634 |         1|
|  1224743 |             6635 |         2|
+----------+------------------+----------+
```

As you can see from the above that the first 3 orders only have 1 location each - so this would be the only location (thus only 1 in this order's sequence), while the order 1224743 has 2 locations and thus 2 in the sequence.

Hope this makes sense and I am looking forward to your responses.
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Get a counter for each duplicate value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463628/mysql-get-a-counter-for-each-duplicate-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer because the accepted answer is really hard to understand if you are novice.
You can order the data in a subquery and make a sequence by counting: if the previous value (prev) of the order_id is the same, add one to sequence, if not, not add anything.

```
select order_id,ship_location_id,sequence
  from (
          select order_id,
                 ship_location_id,
                 @row:=if(@prev=order_id,@row,0) + 1 as sequence,
                 @prev:=order_id
            from tbl
        order by order_id,ship_location_id 
)t
```

Comment: thank you so much! - worked like a charm

Comment: @VoIPX thanks to you to mark it as correct, it really valorates our work. Also is nice if it was useful and clear to you, if you vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

If running MySQL version >= 8.0 you could use ROW_NUMBER() -

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    ship_location_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY ship_location_id) AS sequence
FROM tbl;
```

[MySQL ROW_NUMBER() docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)