# sql how to number rows with similar values

Tags: sql

I have a table like this, user and the project he worked on.

```
User    project
Joe S   P1
Joe S   P1
Joe S   P2
Joe S   P3
Joe S   P3
Joe S   P3
```

I need to add another column by counting similar projects and numbering them

```
job_number  User    project
1           Joe S   P1
2           Joe S   P1
1           Joe S   P2
1           Joe S   P3
2           Joe S   P3
3           Joe S   P3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want Row Number on Group of column in MY SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026956/want-row-number-on-group-of-column-in-my-sql)

Comment: i cannot use row_number() function. SQL i have doesnt support it

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out; I should have also asked you to label the question with the SQL type you are using.

Comment: Please let us know what DBMS you are using. The answer will depend heavily on that.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the work.

**for Oracle**

```
insert into table_name (job_number,user,project) values(nvl(select count(*)+1 from table_name where user='Joe S' and project='p1'),1),'Joe S','p1');
```

**MySQL**

```
insert into table_name (job_number,user,project) values(ifnull(select count(*)+1 from table_name where user='Joe S' and project='p1'),1),'Joe S','p1');
```